# HTTP Google Login - Cookie turned off

Tags: java, cookies, authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to log in to my Google account. I have read in older posts to use [HTTP-Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/httpfox/) to get all parameters. So I added all, including the hidden ones.

```
package com.businessLogic;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class Browser {
 public static void main (String [] arg ){

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service", "lso"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passive", "1209600"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("continue", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?....."));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ltmpl", "embedded"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shdf", "CoMBCxIRdGhpcmR...."));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scc", "1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dsh", "-2602464068824153107"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("GALX", "qqYU2P_8USM"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pstMsg", "1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dnConn", ""));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkConnection", "youtube:816:1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkedDomains", "youtube"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeStmp", ""));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secTok", ""));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_utf8", "â"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bgresponse", "!A0LfAt2vXHmPiURq..."));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", "XXX"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwd", "XXX"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("signIn", "Anmelden"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Response:

```
<html><head><title>Google Accounts</title>
</head>
<body dir="ltr" bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" link="#0000cc" vlink="#551a8b" alink="#ff0000">
<div class="topbar aligns" style="font-size:smaller; margin-bottom:0 15px 1px 15px; white-space:nowrap;">
        <a>
              Google Home
</a>
|

<a>Sign in</a></div>
<div class="header margins" style="height: 40px; margin: 13px 15px 9px 15px;"><a href="https://accounts.google.com/"><img src="/googleaccountslogo/en.gif" border="0" class="floats-normal" alt="Google"></a>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="body"><p>Your browser&#39;s cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on.
[<a href="http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=61416&amp;hl=en&amp;ctx=ch_ServiceLogin&amp;p=lso" target="_blank">?</a>]</p>
&copy;2012 Google

</body></html>
```

The login failed. The "Sign-In" option is also available. I have no idea how to handle these Answer / Cookies. 
I can't find useful solutions because everyone uses the old API where the `httpclient` was a part of the `org.apache.common.*`.

So can you help me?

Comment: If I guess right, then you need to visit the login page first to get a valid session cookie.

Comment: Thats not the solution. I also tried to login at https://accounts.google.com/Login and recieved the same message.

Answer (score 0):

httpFox will show you the cookies for the request in FireFox. Look at those cookies and it should provide some clues for you. One or more of those cookies have to be there, evidently, for that URL to answer you.

http client has a way to specify cookies to be passed with the request/POST.